# Laravel 5 missmatch token in sending email

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, sendmail

i'm using ajax to send email so i my problem is if i dont have

> {!! csrf_field() !!}

in view i will get the token missmatch error.If i add input hidden token in view i will get this error

> Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 348: Address in
>   mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

How can i fix it.Thanks for help.

here it's view

```
 <form action="{{ url('/findpass')}}" method="POST" id="forgotpassForm">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E-mail" name="emailForgot" type="email" id="emailForgot" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="forgotpassBtn" value="Send email">
                            </form>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#forgotpassBtn').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email=$("#emailForgot").val();
        var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/findpass',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                email:email,
                _token : _token  
            },
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data.mess);
                $("#forgotpass")[0].reset();
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });


    });
});
```

Controller

```
public function resetPass()
    {
        $emailForgot=Input::get('emailForgot');
        $user= User::where('email', '=' , $emailForgot)->first();
        $data=['username'=>$user -> username,'email'=>$user -> email,'token'=>$user -> remember_token];
        Mail::send('ui.mail.reset',$data, function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('ngohungphuc95@gmail.com', 'Reset password');
            $m->to($user->email, $user->full_name)->subject('Email reset password');
        });
        return response()->json(array('mess'=>'Mail send'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `csrf` without `blade` and add an `id` by yourself. Get the value of `csrf` value by `id` using `jquery`. Here is how you can do this.

Change `{!! csrf_field() !!}` to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token"/>
```

And Change this line of ajax code:

```
var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
```

To:

```
var _token = $('#token').val();
```

May be this is not the best way. But I solved my problem with this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a global csrf token to all ajax calls like this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        });
    });
```

Then just override the tokensMatch() method of the VerifyCsrfToken token to also look for the ajax header

```
    protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    // If request is an ajax request, then check to see if token matches token provider in
    // the header. This way, we can use CSRF protection in ajax requests also.
    $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

After this all your ajax calls will automatically pass csrf checks and be secure.

Answer (score 0):

> Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 348: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

The above error is because you haven't configured a from address in `config/mail.php`. It is set to null by default, but should be a valid email address:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'user@example.com', 'name' => null],
```